# Conditional assets in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an app with multiple flavours. Assets are flavour-specific, and I'm looking for a way to filter out the assets that don't apply for the current flavour. The current structure looks like

```
assets
  flavour1
    image.jpg
  flavour2
    image.jpg
```

In other words, how do I make sure that when I compile `flavour1` the assets folder gets truncated down to

```
assets
  flavour1
    image.jpg
```

Comment: Why do you need to change the asset (file visibility in project?) dynamically? Do you want to control it in code or by `Theme`?

Comment: I have apps that only differ in assets and some themes. Code is almost identical. I want to merge them under one umbrella project.

Comment: Currently, there is no solution yet. See
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21682

Comment: I also need this functionality for the integration-test where I want to use different data. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This must work since flutter released this : https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors#conditionally-bundling-assets-based-on-flavor